# Gatling during configuration in scenario and 502 Http error

Tags: testing, gatling

When I set the scenario in gatling to run during 1 hour the execution result throw me the next error:

> i.g.h.a.AsyncHandlerActor - Request 'List' failed: status.find.in(200,304,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209), but actually found 502

I tried to add **.disableCaching** and **.shareConnections** in httpConf configuration but I'm in the same situation.

Scenario configuration:

> val filter = scenario("FilterSearch").during(1 hours){exec(Login.login, FilterSearchPurchase.search)}

User injection:

> setUp( 
>       filter.inject(splitUsers(50) into(atOnceUsers(10)) separatedBy(5 minutes)).protocols(httpConf)
>     )

When I try to execute without **.during()** everything goes correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is a network/protocol related problem, see: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb794799.aspx

Comment: Do you run it on AWS? Or where?

Comment: Yes. we launch tests on applications hosted on aws servers.

Comment: Pleas check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446921/why-increasing-worker-connections-in-nginx-makes-the-application-slower-in-node/36143528#36143528 maybe you are dealing with ELB issues.